# Eclipse Error: Websockets are currently only supported in Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to use tomcat in a webapp and want to use Spring’s support for embedding the Tomcat servlet container as the HTTP runtime, instead of deploying to an external instance as it does in the tutorial I am basing my app off of: http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

However, I am getting this stack error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Websockets are currently only supported in Tomcat (found class org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory). 
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.WebSocketAutoConfiguration$1.customize(WebSocketAutoConfiguration.java:74)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:67)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:54)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
... 16 more
```

I'm not sure how it's happening now and not in the Spring example. Here is my POM:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0                      http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-messaging-stomp-websocket</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<url>http://www.springframework.org</url>

<properties>
    <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
    <spring.framework.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
</properties>   

<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-camel</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin> 
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>2.3.2</version> 
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have all of the dependencies that the Spring example uses. What are factors that could affect the application's ability to use Tomcat?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit:

Here is Application.class:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

here is my main:

```
package com.example.integration;

import hello.*;

import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class TestCamelSpring {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("camelspring.xml");
    ProducerTemplate camelTemplate = context.getBean("camelTemplate", ProducerTemplate.class);

    Application.main(args);
    System.out.println("Message Sending started");
    camelTemplate.sendBody("jms:queue:testQSource","Sample Message");
    System.out.println("Message sent");

}
```

}

Comment: what version of tomcat you are using ?

Comment: I'm not even sure. The Spring @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation is supposed to start a Tomcat instance automatically, but that doesn't seem to be happening here. I've added the class with the annotation and the class that calls the previous one to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a jetty dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So you're essentially replacing embedded Tomcat with Jetty. If you don't want Jetty, don't use Jetty dependency.